# Ignite Communication SPI support for IPv6

Tags: java, ignite, ipv6, ipv4

I have read in multiple locations about Ignite having potential issues with IPv6 and we have been seeing similar communication issues within our Kubernetes setup with Ignite, where the communications spi seems to randomly fail.

The Ignite [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#ipv4-vs-ipv6) state that "Ignite tries to support IPv4 and IPv6 but this can sometimes lead to issues where the cluster becomes detached."

While point 4 of this [source](https://dzone.com/articles/a-simple-checklist-for-apache-ignite-beginners) states "It can’t be said that Ignite doesn’t support the IPv6 protocol, but at this moment, there are a few specific problems."

I have two questions:

1. Both of the above sources are very vague, is there any other documentation that describes in detail the issues with IPv6 communication and how to resolve them (apart from using IPv4)?
2. From a practical standpoint, can Ignite function in a purely IPv6 environment? Again any documentation/sources to back this answer up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in many networks, IPv6 is *enabled* but not *configured*, meaning that Ignite can see the address and tries to use it, but no data is routed.

If your IPv6 network is correctly configured and all the nodes can "see" each other, then it should work.